# Rewriting some fraction (Leudesdorf elementary number theory results)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, fractions

In the following $p$ is a prime number, $M(p)$ is a multiple of $p$, $\mu$ is an odd number. In the cited article (see below), page 2 (200), what properties are used to rewrite from line 4 to line 5? That is:

\begin{align}
\frac{p}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\frac{(p-x)^{\mu-1}-\ldots+x^{\mu-1}}{x^{\mu}(p-x)^{\mu}}=\frac{p}{2}\{M(p)-\frac{\mu}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\frac{x^{\mu-1}}{x^{2\mu}}\}
\end{align}

I might see a rewriting like the following for instance:

\begin{align}
\ldots=\frac{p}{2}\{M(p)-\frac{\mu}{2}\sum_{x=1}^{p-1}\frac{x^{\mu-1}}{M(p)-x^{2\mu}}\}
\end{align}

But how to move that $M(p)$ out of the denominator?

*Leudesdorf, C.*, [**Some results in the elementary theory of numbers.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/plms/s1-20.1.199), Lond. M. S. Proc. XX, 199-212 (1889). [ZBL21.0182.03](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:21.0182.03).

Edit: notation unclear, not specified in reference, assume $x$ index for summation.

Comment: What is the summation index for $1$ to $p-1$?

Comment: Edited: I guess $x$, but just copied notation from cited article. You tell me.

Comment: I cannot tell you, because the link is not accessible for me right now. I would like to check the original text.

Comment: I could find it for free easily with a google search. I did not post that link because I was not sure this practice could meet the standards of this site.